# Java read Windows Key State

Tags: java, key, keylistener, jnativehook

I want to write a program that plays a `sound` everytime, a button on the **Keyboard** is pressed. (Even, if the program isn´t in focus)
I am using `JNativeHook`, but when i want to add a `Key Listener`, i get an `error` beacuse the method .**getInstance** isn´t contained in Global Screen. :(
Anyone got an idea?

My Code:

```
package test1;
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class jNativeHookExample implements NativeKeyListener {

    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_F9) {
            //play sound;
        }
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Released: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Typed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            /* Register jNativeHook */
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            /* Its error */
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new jNativeHookExample());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also please post the stacktrace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

This code is probably ok for the version 1.1 of jnativehook.

Starting from the version 2.0 the `GlobalScreen` class has no `getInstance()` method, and `addNativeKeyListener()` is now static, so it should be called directly on the `GlobalScreen`:

```
GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new jNativeHookExample());
```